# UIContainerView call parent method

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uicontainerview

I am a very new iOS dev and need your help.

I have a simple app, made from:

1 view controller that contains

- 3 UIContainerView, each one is linked to its own view controller and class
- A view (the player)

Here is an image of my storyboard so it will be easier to understant:
[image]
 => I need 10 rep to post the image as an image

What I want is that when I click the play button on the cell inside "View Controller Search" it calls a method or function from the parent (main?) view controller including the url of the file to play.

I have already a working action on the play button, I have found how to get the url from it and printed it using NSLog so everything is fine from this part. My only problem is to find a way to communicate with the main view by sending the url.

If hope I am clear enough, thank you for your time.

Comment: use property to access your parent `self.parentViewController`

Answer (score 1):

You've got two options:

1. The quick and dirty one is to use the `parentViewController` property of your contained controller, cast it to the type of the parent view controller and call a method on it.
2. The right way is to define a delegate protocol and property for your search view controller, and make the parent view controller conform to it. Then, in the `prepareForSegue:` of the parent view controller, set the parent as the search controller's delegate.

`prepareForSegue:` will be called three times when your parent view controller is loaded, once for each **embed segue** that you have defined in the storyboard above. Just like when you push on a navigation controller, this is your opportunity to configure the destination view controller. You can give each embed segue in your storyboard an identifier to help with this process.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am very new to obj-c but i ll check about this delegate solution. Do you have any simple tutorial/exemple to advice?